# Creating an m by n matrix of 0s and 1s from m-sized vector of column indexes

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

I have a *m*-dimensional vector of integers ranging from 1 to *n*. These integers are column indexes for *m × n* matrix.

I want to create a *m × n* matrix of 0s and 1s, where in *m*-th row there's a 1 in the column that is specified by *m*-th value in my vector.

Example:

```
% my vector (3-dimensional, values from 1 to 4):
v = [4;
     1;
     2];

% corresponding 3 × 4 matrix
M = [0 0 0 1;
     1 0 0 0;
     0 1 0 0];
```

Is this possible without a for-loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, that's why they invented [sparse](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/sparse.html) matrices:

```
>> M = sparse(1:length(v),v,ones(length(v),1))
M =

   (2,1)        1
   (3,2)        1
   (1,4)        1
```

which you can convert to a full matrix if you want with [full](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/full.html):

```
>> full(M)
ans =

     0     0     0     1
     1     0     0     0
     0     1     0     0
```

Answer (score 3):

Or without sparse matrix:

```
>> M = zeros(max(v),length(v));
>> M(v'+[0:size(M,2)-1]*size(M,1)) = 1;
>> M = M'

M =

 0     0     0     1
 1     0     0     0
 0     1     0     0
```

Transposition is used because in matlab arrays are addressed by columns

Answer (score 3):

In Octave, at least as of 3.6.3, you can do this easily using broadcasting:

```
M = v==1:4
```