# Filling matrix with ones depending on vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, octave

In Octave, I have a vector with indexes e.g. `a = [ 1 2 3 1 2 3]`. I now want a matrix `m = zeros(size(a,2), max(a))` to have ones depending on vector a:

```
m =
[1 0 0
 0 1 0
 0 0 1
 1 0 0
 0 1 0
 0 0 1]
```

How do I do that?

I tried this, but it didn't work: `m(a,:) = 1;`

Comment: in your specific case you can do `[eye(3); eye(3)]`

Comment: That's true, but a could also be `a = [1 1 3 2 1 3]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an m by n matrix of 0s and 1s from m-sized vector of column indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665179/creating-an-m-by-n-matrix-of-0s-and-1s-from-m-sized-vector-of-column-indexes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming:

```
a = [1 2 3 1 2 3];
sz = [numel(a), max(a)];
```

using `sub2ind`:

```
m = zeros(sz);
ind = sub2ind(sz, 1:sz(1), a);
m(ind) = 1;
```

using `sparse`

```
m = full(sparse(1:sz(1), a, 1));
```

Comment: Nice answer. IMO, the following is a bit simpler `full(sparse(1:numel(a), a, 1))`.

Comment: @user1406177 Look at the last answer to this duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10665179/creating-an-m-by-n-matrix-of-0s-and-1s-from-m-sized-vector-of-column-indexes it makes use of broadcasting in Octave whih Matlab doesn't have and is much simpler. However, I would recommend against using this method as you will remove compatibility with Matlab which, even if it seems irrelevant to you now, is probably something worth preserving as it makes you code portable.

Answer (score 0):

You can also index into an identity matrix like so.

```
a = [ 1 2 3 1 2 3];

I = eye(max(a));
m = I(a, :);
```